# How does Material UI Tab Indicator style override work?

Tags: material-ui

On the [Customized tabs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#customized-tabs) section of the documentation we see it defining a component `AntTab` with the `withStyles` api:

```
const AntTabs = withStyles({
  root: {
    borderBottom: '1px solid #e8e8e8',
  },
  indicator: {
    backgroundColor: '#1890ff',
  },
})(Tabs);
```

But the `indicator` class rule is not listed on [Tab CSS api](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/#css) (and I don't seem to find the class in the source code as well)

So my question is: How is material-ui able to understand this CSS rule? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.

I was looking at the wrong api. It should be the [Tabs CSS Api](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/)